# How did the time loop in Dimension C-137 work?

Tags: rick-and-morty

As shown in "Solaricks", Rick created a time loop in C-137 of that day his family was killed. Mr. Goldmanbachmajorian said this:

> I was hoping you could help me make sense of a note I found this morning? It's written by someone claiming to be me. They say my mind is  'held captive in a time loop, trapped in the day of a traumatic event by  the agony of a formidable intelligence, but also that my captor forgot about aging, that my body spoils and yearns for death while my soul remains stuck in place, caught like a fly in amber.'

How could that day keep repeating but everyone still ages? Did time keep going for everyone to age and the events just keep repeating? That doesn't make sense. I'm not sure after taking minutes to think about it, I don't watch much Sci-Fi other than R&M. I wonder if this is one of those things where not much thought was put into how it works and that's just it.

Answer (score 7):

My answer would be: it is not technically speaking a time loop but a mind loop. Pure speculation from evidence from other episodes.

"Your mind is trapped in time loop". Rick doesn't mess with time travel because if you do that you get under the watchful eye and on the bad side of Time Police.
(like this guy: https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/Shleemypants ) I wonder how Rick found that out in the first place? Maybe he tried to turn back time to prevent Diane's death and settled on "stopping the time" as a second choice?

Even in other episodes, when he provided Morty with "save point" device, he wasn't really messing with time but with dimensions and the episode ends with Rick merging all dimensions affected by Morty's shenanigans into one.

On the other hand, as "Morty's Mindblowers" shows, Rick has no problem messing with people's bodies, minds and memories. So instead of messing with time (which would get him stopped by Time Police), he has messed with the memories of the whole world (and maybe the whole dimension!). He made a save point of their mental state in the morning and puts it into their heads every night, overwriting their memories of the day. So they repeat their last day, as if frozen in time, forgetting they have done so thousands of times already. And by his own words, he did a shoddy work of that, he wasn't in the best mental state and was sloppy.

Comment: The fact that people keep aging also proves that there wasn't anything actually being done to time.